# Java 8 Filtering Map and Producing a List

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to filter a java.util.Map produce a List of the values from the Map.  Here's what I tried:

```
protected Map<String, BaseObject> resources;

List<Resource> qualifyingResources = this.resources.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getType().equals(inputType))
            .collect(Collectors.toList(entry -> (Resource) entry.getValue()));
```

I get the following compile error.

```
[javac] C:\iPipeline_Repos\resonant-guardian\server\buildsrc\com\resonant\guardian\services\nbs\Inbound103Processor.java:4490: error: method toList in class Collectors cannot be applied to given types;
[javac]                 .collect(Collectors.toList(entry -> (Resource) entry.getValue()));
[javac]                                    ^
[javac]   required: no arguments
[javac]   found: (entry)->([...]lue()
[javac]   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
[javac]     (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
[javac]   where T is a type-variable:
[javac]     T extends Object declared in method <T>toList()
```

Any ideas how to correct?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

`required: no arguments` should be your first clue.  [The documentation of that method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) should be your second clue.  When you are having trouble with a method, always check its documentation first.

[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) the Stream elements to Resource objects, *then* collect them into a List.

And since you only care about the Map’s values, why bother with the Map’s entries?  Just make a Stream from the values:

```
//                          values, not entrySet ─────┐
List<Resource> qualifyingResources = this.resources.values().stream()
        .filter(value -> value.getType().equals(inputType))
        .map(value -> (Resource) value)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should you [map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) for intermediate operation for mapping value into another

```
List<Resource> qualifyingResources = this.resources.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getType().equals(inputType))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

FYI, the [Collectors.toList()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()) will not accept any arguments, and i would recommend this nice [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-maps-streams) on streams

If the `key` is never used then you can simply stream the values itself

```
    List<Resource> qualifyingResources = this.resources.values().stream()
        .filter(value -> value.getType().equals(inputType))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what is causing this problem is that you are misusing `Collectors.toList()`
as you are providing arguments for toList() while this method doesn't accept arguments the error log shows this error
**[javac]   required: no arguments**

you can check this documentation on how to use `Collectors.toList()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--

I would recommend you do the following:

```
this.resources.entrySet().stream()
 .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getType().equals(inputType))
 .map(entry->(Resource) entry.getValue())
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```